# How to make sub terms show in main taxonomy page in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, view, ubercart

I have categories:

- Cameras (4)

  - Accessories (2)
  - Bags and Casings (2)

    - Inner (1)
    - Outer (1)

If I open cameras, I see nothing, only:

```
There is currently no content classified with this term.
```

Instead, I want the view to automatically show the children if I click on "Cameras". Clicking on cameras should therefore show all the contents of Accessories and also bags and casings and inner and outer. If I click on Bags and Casings, it must only show bags and casings, inner and outer.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried adding the **contextual filter** `Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)` of to the view?  See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/58526